# I want to change the colour of the nav bar on this page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to work with - http://startbootstrap.com/templates/full.html#about

But I just cannot change the colour of the black bar along the top to blue. I just can't find the code for it in the CSS or relate to it in html.

Can anyone help? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use **[DevTools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/index)** to inspect the element.

```
.navbar-inverse {
    background-color: #222;
    border-color: #080808;
}
```

That line defines the color of the bar.